# Find the equation of the line that bisects the inner angle of the triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

A triangle is formed by the lines $x-2y-6=0$ , $ 3x−y+6=0$, $7x+4y−24=0$.

Find the equation of the line that bisects the inner angle of the triangle that is facing the side $7x+4y−24=0$.

I tried to find the intersect point of three equations by put them equal two by two. However, I don't know what to do next. could someone help me, please?

Comment: I think something is not true in the given. The answer turns out very ugly.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I double checked the question just to make sure I copied it properly. How is the answer?

Comment: We get $\frac{|x-2y-6|}{\sqrt5}=\frac{|3x-y+6|}{\sqrt10}$ or $\sqrt2|x-2y-6|=|3x-y+6|$, which says that that answer will be with $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: if point $P(x,y)$ is in the bisector of angle between two lines $x-2y-6=0$ and $3x-y+6=0$, then the distances from this point to each lines are equal. So, you get two lines which are bisector. Check which is the inner bisector.

HINT 2: See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) for distance between point $P(x_0,y_0)$ and the line $ax+by+c=0$. Using this formula, you have distance from $P(x_0,y_0)$ to two lines. Solve the system of equations, you get $P$.

Comment: I don't know how to find point P. Can you hint me more?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with triangle. You have two lines $x-2y=6$ and $3x-y=6$, intersecting at the point $P=(6/5,-12/5)$, and want an equation for the line bisecting the angle, presumably with positive slope. My suggestion, perhaps not as good as that of @GAVD, is to take any other point $Q_1$ on the first line, find its distance $d$ from $P$, and then find a point $Q_2$ on the second line at a distance of $d$ from $P$. Then build the rhombus whose vertices are, in order, $Q_1,P,Q_2,P'$, and draw the bisector from $P$ to $P'$. If you’re doing it by hand computation, it’ll be a mess.

Comment: The triangle tells you which of the two bisectors to choose.